# How to remove the board border of pinterest widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pinterest

Can anyone please help me to remove the board border of the Pinterest Board widget!! Struggling to remove it by using "border: none" or "border: 0" but nothing  is happening!

```html
<a data-pin-do="embedUser" data-pin-board-width="400" data-pin-scale-height="240" data-pin-scale-width="80" href="https://in.pinterest.com/anubhavgkp97/"></a>
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border is actually a `box-shadow`.

You can remove it with `box-shadow: none`.

The Pinterest script injects a number of HTML elements in to the document with random classes making it difficult to target the required element. I would suggest adding a wrapper element to make this easier.

```css
.widget-wrapper > span {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-wrapper">
  <a data-pin-do="embedUser" data-pin-board-width="400" data-pin-scale-height="240" data-pin-scale-width="80" href="https://in.pinterest.com/anubhavgkp97/"></a>
  <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
</div>
```